# Celery: How to ignore task result in chord or chain?

Tags: python, asynchronous, task, celery

I'm using celery, I have several tasks which needed to be executed in order.

For example I have this task:

```
@celery.task
def tprint(word):
    print word
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
>>> chain(tprint.s('a') | tprint.s('b'))()
```

Then I get `TypeError: tprint() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.

The same with chord, in this situation which I need a task to be executed after a group of tasks:

```
>>> chord([tprint.s('a'), tprint.s('b')])(tprint.s('c'))
```

So how to deal with this situation? I don't care the result of each task, but they need to be executed in order.

---

Add a second parameter won't work:

```
@celery.task
def tprint(word, ignore=None):
    print word

>>> chain(tprint.s('a', 0) | tprint.s('b'))()
```

This will print out 'a' and 'None'.

Comment: celery chord header uses a group, which executes in parallel, so you shouldn't be using it if the order is relevant

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There is a built-in functionality to ignore result in chaining and others - immutable subtask. You can use .si() shortcut instead of .s() or .subtask(immutable=True)

More details here: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#immutability

Comment: upvoted! i read the docs but still havent understood the terminology, what exactly is immutability supposed to do if you dont mind sharing

Comment: They seem to abuse the term, but the idea behind this option is simple. It marks the function as one that does not expect a result from a chained computation passed to its arguments.

Comment: I now understand what `si` is used for, thanks!

Comment: That link points to a 404. The new location is: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#immutability

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the link. Thanks @sc3000

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution has already posted, but I'd like to add further clarification and an alternate solution (and in some cases a superior one).

The error you're seeing, which indicates that your task's signature needs to take into account a second parameter, is due to the fact that when calling tasks in a `chain`, Celery automatically pushes each tasks `result` as the first parameter of the following task.

From the [docs:](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains)

> Tasks can be linked together, which in practice means adding a callback task:

```
>>> res = add.apply_async((2, 2), link=mul.s(16))
>>> res.get()
4
```

> The linked task will be applied with the result of its parent task as the first argument

Therefore, in your case, you could rewrite your task like this:

```
@celery.task
def tprint(result, word):
    print word
```

<strike>If you're not going to do anything with the result, you may as well ignore it, by [changing the decorator thus](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.ignore_result):</strike>

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
```

And then you won't have to change your task signature.

Sorry, that last point needs further research.

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing something like this.
Instead of having a single parameter for function tprint you can have 2 parameters

```
def tprint(word, x=None):
    print word
```

then

```
chain(tprint.s('a', 0) | tprint.s('b'))()
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `*ignore, **kwignore` arguments to cover any combination

Comment: This solution does not generalize.  If he needs to chain 3 functions, would you add a 3rd parameter to also ignore?  You are messing up the function's namespace and overall semantics.  The .si() recommendation is the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

Finally find a workaround for this, a chain decorator will do this job.

I don't know how exactly celery did it, but celery seems force bind previous task's result to next task's first argument.

So here's an example:

```
def chain_deco(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(chain=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if chain is False:
            return False

        func(*args, **kwargs)
        return True

    return wrapper


@celery.task
@chain_deco
def hello(word):
    print "hello %s" % word
```

Now this will give the right output.

```
>>> (hello.s(word='a') | hello.s(word='b'))()
```

OR

```
>>> (hello.s('a') | hello.s('b'))(True)
```

And decorator also provide the ability to stop a chain in the middle(make the later cascade fail.)

The same mechanism should work for `chord` too.